# Clone JPA entity where children have multiple parents

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity, relationship

I have an "interesting" structure for entities and I'm stuck trying to clone them. I basically have one super-parent that I'm cloning. Let's call this class `Document`. A document has at least one `Function` and one `Component`. Now this part isn't an issue, these are `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` and I can clone them just fine. But now there is a third class that belongs to both `Function` and `Component` - let's call it an `Interaction`. By design this is part of both the `Function` and the `Component` as it described something that both do when interacting.

Now in a normal flow there would be an order for creation, where a `Document` is created first, then at least one `Component` and `Function` is created automatically. After that `Interactions` can be created. You can imagine this like a matrix, where an `Interaction` described how one `Component` interacts with one `Function`. Generally speaking `Component` and `Function` are not related and can exist independently, though at least one of each will always exist so that the matrix exists.

Now the issue is cloning an entire document. When cloning all the nested entities must be cloned and keep their relations. However IDs are not known at clone time (as they must be unset or new entities created) so I'm not sure how to prevent duplicates here.

How would one clone this entire `Document` and it's sub-relations with new IDs and keep all the relations intact? I know this is easy if all the relations are in a "linear" structure, but multiple parents appear to be difficult.

Here is a diagram for clarity:

[image: ERD]

`Document.java`

```
@Table(name = "document")
@Entity
public class Document {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "document", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Component> components = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "document", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Function> functions = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

`Component.java`

```
@Table(name = "component")
@Entity
public class Component {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Document document;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "component", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Interaction> interactions;

}
```

`Function.java`

```
@Table(name = "function")
@Entity
public class Function {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Document document;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "function", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Interaction> interactions;

}
```

`Interaction.java`

```
@Table(name = "interaction")
@Entity
public class Interaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Function function;

    @ManyToOne
    private Component component;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For copying a graph one usually has to build an identity map from source to target and query that before doing a copy. Something like this:

```
interface CustomClonable {
  Object clone(Map<Object, Object> mapping);
}

public static <T extends CustomClonable> T clone(T original, Map<Object, Object> mapping) {
  Object copy = mapping.get(original);
  if (copy == null) {
    copy = original.clone(mapping);
    mapping.put(original, copy);
  }
  return (T) copy;
}
```

All your type implement that interface and clone themselves, invoking the static clone method for nested objects.